# Kotlin: At which situations does implicit conversion happen?

Tags: kotlin, type-conversion

I am a beginner in Kotlin.
I'm most familiar with Python, and I just read through the basic Java Tutorial https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html before jumping into Kotlin.

A question came up in my mind while reading this section of the documentation of Kotlin

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#explicit-conversions

What I have understood from above section of the documentation is:

- For assignments `=`, implicit type conversion happens. If the lefthand side's type is a supertype or same type of righthand side's type the code would compile. Otherwise it's a compile error. In case of `Int` and `Long`, they are both subtypes of `Number` but neither of them subtypes of each other, so the implicit conversion would not work. Therefore we need to use methods like .toLong() or .toInt() to explicitly convert them.

Then when I read the part

> ```
> val l = 1L + 3 // Long + Int => Long
> ```

I started wondering if implicit type conversion would be taking place in this situation.

The documentation says this has to do with the operator overloading.
How is this operator overloading implemented under the hood?
I tried to find the source code at Github https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/core/builtins/native/kotlin/Primitives.kt ,
but here the functions are only declared but not implemented. Where can I find the implementations?

It seems that operation overloading does not actually perform type conversion. Do we just implementing all possible functions with same name but different parameter type signatures, so that the type is inferred, then the function with the matching signature is selected?

And the general question: In Kotlin, exactly at which situations does implicit conversion happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For assignments =, implicit type conversion happens. If the lefthand side's type is a supertype or same type of righthand side's type the code would compile.

Assignments aren't special in this. More generally, if the expected type of an expression is a supertype or the same as actual type, the code compiles; it's just that the expected type for the right-hand side of an assignment is the left-hand side's type. I wouldn't say there is an implicit conversion inserted, but I don't think anything breaks if you see it that way.

> Do we just implementing all possible functions with same name but different parameter type signatures, so that the type is inferred, then the function with the matching signature is selected?

Yes, exactly (for this case). If you want to support primitive types, you need to provide overloads for all of them.

So `1L + 3` is just a method call so far as the parsing and type-checking is concerned ([`Long.plus(Int): Long](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings) specifically), no implicit conversion is involved. But these methods are built into the compiler to handle specially which is why you don't see an implementation.

It becomes two [bytecode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings) instructions `i2l` ("convert an int into a long") and `ladd` ("add two longs"), but that's not something you should probably care about yet, or for a long time.

> And the general question: In Kotlin, exactly at which situations does implicit conversion happen?

[Smart casts](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#smart-casts) are the closest Kotlin has to implicit conversions but they are sufficiently different from i.c.s in other languages that I wouldn't use the name. So I'd say never.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So in an assignment, it's not that an implicit conversion was inserted, but just that the type of the right-hand side of an assignment matched the type of the left-hand side (meaning, <type of RHS> is either <type of LHS> or its subtype). Then if I understood correctly, in Kotlin there is no such thing as implicit type conversion, just except the case for number literals (e.g. `val a: Long = 1` where 1 is Int).

Comment: @jazzinpark Yes, exactly.