# Is there a way to define an implicit ctor for a Kotlin class?

Tags: kotlin, implicit-conversion

as the title says it, is there any way to define a constructor or convertion for a class/object that can be called implicitly like this?

```
class Person {
    val name: String
    val mood: Mood = Mood.Happy

    fun toString(): String = "$name is $mood"
}

fun main() {

    // Calls the magic implicit ctor
    val steve: Person = "Steve"

    // Prints "Steve is happy"
    println("$steve")
}
```

Comment: Not possible. There is no implicit conversions in Kotlin, let alone user defined ones. See [this](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/type-conversions/828/2) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60295835/kotlin-at-which-situations-does-implicit-conversion-happen).

Comment: It would be nice to have the option, but as i see in the links, Kotlin deliberately avoids any implicit conversions. Thank you @Sweeper